# How to autosize height of UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a `UITableView` with `Style=Grouped` (though there aren't any groupings, I just like the style that it produces). Usually this `UITableView` has 2 or 3 rows in it depending on the situation.

How can I autosize the `UITableView` based on the number of rows?  Keep in mind that with `Style=Grouped`, there is a chunk of white space at the top of the `UITableView`.  I'd like for there to be a similar space at the bottom of the `UITableView`.

I am doing this with Xamarin/C#, but Objective C answers are fine too.

Comment: What do you mean "autosize"?  UITableView calculates that for you.

Answer (score 1):

UITableView extends UIScrollView so after reloading the table view use -[UIScrollView contentSize] and -[UIScrollView contentInset] to get the height of the content then set the table view's frame height

Answer (score 0):

There are methods in [UITableViewDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) to specify the height for each object in a table view (either directly, with something like `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, or indirectly with things like `viewForHeaderInSection` - where you can return a view with a `size` property of whatever you want).  `Height of header + Height of footer + (height of cell * number of cells)` will give you how much room you need to fit the whole table without scrolling.

If you're not implementing any of those methods, the current (iOS 6) defaults are 30, 18, and 44 respectively.